# How to make UIStackView with yours SubViews with different sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

I wants create a ViewController with UIScrollView, UIStackView (Vertical), UILabel and UITableView. But my problem is that I can't set different height sizes to my Views. I did tried write in the field, but XCode erases and set back value. I did tried all options of distribuitions, but I think that my option is "Equal Spacing".

I've added two UIView to test.

[image]

[image]

I did can make my screen, but this not works on iPhone device and XCode says that it's impossible adjust constraints automatically. This is my objective:

[image]

Some fields needs different height sizes. Some labels need 3 lines, other 1 line.

Comment: Why you have to make it a stackView , what about to make the top part a table with automatic height cell

Comment: I think complicate to handler click on tableview item

Answer (score 0):

If you add constraints to all subviews i.e. top and bottom it will work correctly. Make sure you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false

Answer (score 0):

in the current Xcode (15) you can just set "Autoresizes Subviews" to false.
then all the "child" rows can be different sizes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a height constraint in order for your view to have a specific height within the stack view. [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I added a link to the apple's documentation. Maybe it becomes clearer this way. You want to look at the "Pin Tool" section. Click on your view, then on the button shown in the picture of that section and then set a fixed height.

Comment: Yout link not contains that I  need

Comment: I edited my previous comment. The Pin-Tool section should help.

Comment: This link open a github page with third party library